# Use javascript to click all images based on src value only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to click all the links on a page that have a certain image src.

I know I can do the following if I know the id:

```
alert(document.getElementById('image').src);
```

But I know know the src and nothing else is there. No id, alt or title, nothing only src.

Anyone have any idea on how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: `$('a[href]').has('img[src=' + thesrc + ']').click();`

Answer (score 3):

Easy.. though please read jquery's documentation when you get the chance:

```
$("img[src='src_goes_here']").trigger("click");
```

Assuming you want to click the link that has a child image with a particular source..

```
$("a img[src='src_goes_here']").parent().trigger("click");
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be looking for a link?

Comment: @JaredFarrish They said the links have 'image source' the didn't say 'links which have an image with a source'.. though I'll fix it to that case as well, just because.

Comment: This just sends the click event but doesn't following the parent href, how would you do a real mouse 'click'?

Comment: Here's a demo (using `document.links` to scope it down a bit).

Comment: @Calsin - Of course. You would need to set `window.location` with the link element's `href`: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/P8rEt/1/

Comment: @Calsin Jared's above example is the only way to do that.

Comment: So you must use the on method, is there now way to do it which an extra button?

Comment: @Calsin - Note there was a typo in the first image's `src` value: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/P8rEt/2/

Comment: @Calsin The method used in the example is window.location.  The button is just part of the example.

Comment: @Calsin - That was just to make the demo useful; you can trigger the link clicking at your leisure.

Comment: Seems there is a onclick="toggletop1()" function on the page I'm trying to run it on that is hijacking the demo. Any way around that?

Comment: @Calsin If the event is inline.. I personally don't see a way around it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean with "clicking links with a certain image-src", as clicking would be a user-interaction and links don't tend to have a `src` - attribute like the `<img>`-tag

Anyhow, using jQuery as example, there is something called "Attribute-Selectors", in your case the [Attribute Equals Selector (jQuery-API)](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) should do the trick:

```
var yourSource = "/path/to/image.jpg";
var myImages = $('img[src="'+ yourSource +'"]');
```

So, for example, if your images are *inside* a link, all you'd need to do is:

```
myImages.parent().trigger('click');
```

but I really don't know what good that should do

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img[src="' + yourKnownSrc +  '"]').click();
```

In case you want to click links "having" an image:

```
$('a').has('img[src="' + yourKnownSrc +  '"]').click();
```